# How to wait without stopping script?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple website, [ProjectX2](http://www.projectx2.zzl.org), in which users can message each other.

I have a PHP function containing the number of new messages the user has that I want to "refresh" every 20 seconds. It takes information from a database.

When I call this function, it only has the number of new messages from the page load - it doesn't update itself every time I call it. I'm calling it from JavaScript like so:

```
        function pum() {
            document.getElementById("usermessages").innerHTML = "<?php echo pum() ?>";
        }
        window.setInterval(pum,20000);
```

For example, if I have 5 new messages at the beginning of my visit, it will not change unless I reload the webpage.

I have tried using an infinite loop:

```
while(true) {
    pum();
    sleep(20000);
}
```

but this method doesn't let the page load in the background.

So, my question is, how do I *just* refresh the function? Is there a method similar to `sleep()` where the page can load in the background?

Comment: look at the page source for your site - you will be setting innerHTML to a constant value because the php code is only evaluated when the page is rendered. I.e. it _will_ be being updated (assuming no script errors) every 20 seconds but to exactly the same string. as @PHPGlue has (poorly) answered you need to make a xhr request (e.g. [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the contents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AJAX inside of `setInterval()`.

Comment: AJAX makes server calls from JavaScript and will not cause the entire page to reload.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not run client-side. It's generated before it's served to the end user. Therefore, by the time you load the page, you will have a block that looks like this:

```
function pum() {
    document.getElementById("usermessages").innerHTML = "5";
}
```

Notice how the **5** is in there statically. No matter how many times you call this function it's only going to return 5 because the PHP on the page has already executed and the script is closed. It will contain whatever the value `pum()` contained at the time of page load.

You need to make a new file, call it pum.php that simply contains `echo pum();` and closes. You can then use AJAX to request this file and append it to your element.